# How to reference a file in Eclipse that is not in src

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I'm trying to get a resource for MyBatis. The tutorial states that I will need the following in my Connection Factory:

```
String resource = "org/mybatis/example/Configuration.xml";
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
```

My directory structure is:

src/
  com/
    utils/
      MyBatisConnectionFactory.java
config/
  Configuration.xml

I am having troubles referencing the configuration file. I tried "config/Configuration.xml", "Configuration.xml" and "/config/Configuration.xml".

Anyone have a good idea for what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your `config` directory as a source-folder (right-click > build path > use as source folder).

Thus your configuration files will go on the root of the classpath and will be accessible via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Configuration.xml")`

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do in on MyEclipse?

Comment: MyEclipse is just an addition to eclipse, so it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file via the classpath using `getResourcesAsStream()` rather than `Resources.getResourceAsReader()` For example:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
    "src/com/utils/Configuration.xml");
byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(data);
is.close();
String fileContents = new String(data);
```