# MyBatis loading XML : java.io.IOException: Could not find resource (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, mybatis

I found strange behaviour while using MyBatis with Eclipse.

I have difficulty with MyBatis with finding my xml, so I tried to use absolute path (just for testing purposes) and it still throw error :

To be sure that file exists, I added check for file existence before using it as Resource, so I am sure that this file exists :

```
        String resource = "e:/prace/workspace/SpringBatis/src/main/java/com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml";// path of the mybatis configuration file.
        File file = new File(resource);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);// read the mybatis confiuguration xml file
```

Having this output :

```
true
java.io.IOException: Could not find resource e:/prace/workspace/SpringBatis/src/main/java/com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:89)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327479/how-to-reference-a-file-in-eclipse-that-is-not-in-src)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 scenarios

1. Reading the file using java io. Since You had given absolute path. It will always read the file if it exists.

   ```
       String resource = "e:/prace/workspace/SpringBatis/src/main/java/com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml";// path of the mybatis configuration file.
       File file = new File(resource);
       System.out.println(file.exists());
       Reader reader = new FileReader(resource);
   ```
2. The scenario where you are trying to read config file is using Resources (which is your primary goal I believe). Resources class always tries to read file from class path.  Here is java comment from the Resources.java class as a proof.

   ```
   /*
     * Gets a URL as a Reader
     *
     *  @param urlString - the URL to get
     * @return A Reader with the data from the URL
     * @throws java.io.IOException If the resource cannot be found or read
   */
   public static Reader getUrlAsReader(String urlString) throws IOException {}
   ```

**Now how to resolve this**
From the folder structure I assume you are using the Maven. Hence by default your classpath would be `SpringBatis/src/main/java` or `SpringBatis/src/main/resources` Hence you can provide the resource path as `com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml`, in your case currently Resources path turns out be `e:/prace/workspace/SpringBatis/src/main/java/e:/prace/workspace/SpringBatis/src/main/java/com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml`

Thus your code would should look like.

```
 String resource = "com/mkyong/MyBatis/xml/batisConfig.xml";// path of the mybatis configuration file.
               // File file = new File(resource);
                System.out.println(file.exists());
               // Reader reader = new FileReader(resource);
```

If you are using eclipse you can verify the classpath as follows. 
Right on project->project properties-> java build path -> sources tab.
You should find all th relevant classpaths. For example for your project SpringBatis you would find SpringBatis/main/java with included files, excluded files, out directory etc.

**Note**
Since you have placed batisConfig.xml under src/main/java. By default maven configures to include only `*/*.java` file( only java files) if need to include all the files you need to configure accordingly. But I would recommend to move the xml file to src/main/resources directory( which is again a classpath)